# Use of unresolved identifier: PFTwitterUtils swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, parse-platform

Currently I'm trying to implement a twitter user  login for my app in Xcode 7 beta with parse. I followed the docs at parse.com for twitter. After implementing, I am still running to use of unresolved identifier for

```
PFTwitterUtils.initializeWithConsumerKey("somekey",  consumerSecret:"somekey")
```

and

```
@IBAction func twitterButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        PFTwitterUtils.logInWithBlock {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {
                    // process user object
                    self.processTwitterUser()
                } else {
                    // process user object
                    self.processTwitterUser()
                }
            } else {
                print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.")
            }
        }

    }
```

and

```
 func processTwitterUser()
    {
    // Show activity indicator
    let spiningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    spiningActivity.labelText = "Loading"
    spiningActivity.detailsLabelText = "Please wait"

    let pfTwitter = PFTwitterUtils.twitter()

    let twitterUsername =  pfTwitter?.screenName

    var userDetailsUrl:String = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name="
    userDetailsUrl = userDetailsUrl + twitterUsername!

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: userDetailsUrl);
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET";

    pfTwitter!.signRequest(request);
```

any common pitfalls I might have fell into? 
Note: I added the correct frameworks (accounts etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that worked for me.

1. I added the "ParseTwitterUtils.framework"
2. In my Bridging header I added "#import ParseTwitterUtils/ParseTwitterUtils.h  "
3. In my AppDelegate.Swift I added "import ParseTwitterUtils"
4. I filled the consumerKey and secretKey (You'll find them on your Twitter dev account)

And now it's working

Hope it helped